# how to extract last value in the URL using JQuery

Tags: jquery

how to extract the last value that is 1 from the following Url using jQuery...

Url : /FormBuilder/index.php/reports/export/1

Answer (score 40):

You can use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/substring) and [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
var value = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

If the second parameter of [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/substring) is omitted, it extracts the characters to the end of the string.

Comment: 5 seconds! You sneaky Guatemalan :)

Comment: @Andy: LOL exactly 5 sec, that was really close!

Answer (score 9):

To get it from the URL Address:

```
var value = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

Not really jQUery, but pure Javascript:

```
var a = '/test/foo/bar';
```

To get the string after the last character:

```
var result = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a regex, which is just like the `lastIndexOf` method, but with the added benefit of being almost impossible to read/understand! `;)`

```
var lastBit = theUrl.match(/[^\/]*$/)[0];
```

There actually IS a benefit though, if you only wanted to get trailing numbers, or some other pattern you could adapt it:

```
// match "/abc/123", not "/abc/foo"
var lastDigits = theUrl.match(/[0-9]*$/)[0];

// match "/abc/Pie", not "/abc/123"
var matches = theUrl.match(/\/(P[^\/]*)$/);
var lastBitWhichStartsWithTheLetterP = matches ? matches[1] : null;
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from all of the answers JQuery isn't needed to do this.

You could split it:

```
var url = 'www.google.com/dir1/dir2/2';
var id = parseInt(url.split('/')[url.split('/').length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a regex?

```
var p = /.+\/([^\/]+)/;
var match = p.exec(str)
alert(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = window.location.split("/FormBuilder/index.php/reports/export/1");
var last_val = arr[arr.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Universal:**

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
    var pathname = window.location.pathname.split("/");

    for (i = 0; i < pathname.length; i++) {
        if (pathname[i] == variable){
            return pathname[i+1];
        }
    }

}
```